# Enable button only if start and end dates are not empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Initially my `button` is in disabled mode. When a user selects both start and end dates only then it should be enabled to download.

The below code enables the button when only start or end date is selected. How could I enable download button only when both inputs are not empty by applying class `$('#btn_download').attr('class','btn-general');`?

```
//enable 'Download' button only if Start-End dates are not empty
var enableDisableBtn = function(){
    var startVal = $('#datepicker_start').val().trim();
    var endVal = $('#datepicker_end').val().trim();
    var disableBtn =  startVal.length == 0 || endVal.length == 0;
    $('#btn_download').attr('disabled',disableBtn);
    $('#btn_download').attr('class','btn-general');
}   

$('#datepicker_start').datepicker({
    enableDisableBtn();
});

$('#datepicker_end').datepicker({
    enableDisableBtn();
});
```

```html
<button class="btn-general disabled" id="btn_download" type="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" style="margin-right:5px;"></span>
    Download
</button>
```

```css
.btn-general {
    background-color: #6eb8d9;
    color: #fff;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.btn-general.disabled {
    background-color: #5bc0de;
    color: #fff;
    pointer-events:none;
    cursor:not-allowed;
    opacity:0.40;
}
```

Comment: Why are you invoking function `enableDisableBtn` when initializing `datepicker`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [onClose](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onClose) option

> Called when the datepicker is closed, whether or not a date is selected.

*Script*

```
var enableDisableBtn = function(){
    var startVal = $('#datepicker_start').val().trim();
    var endVal = $('#datepicker_end').val().trim();
    var disableBtn =  startVal.length == 0 || endVal.length == 0;
    $('#btn_download').prop('disabled',disableBtn).addClass('btn-general');
}   

//Set up onClose
$('#datepicker_start, #datepicker_end').datepicker({
    onClose : function(){
         enableDisableBtn();
    }
});

//Call initially
enableDisableBtn();
```

Comment: Satpal: The function is called `onClose` event, but somehow the class is is not applied and it remains `disabled` even if both start and end dates are selected

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy, you never add / remove the class `disabled`, just the property

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy Ah right, your code looks like you try to set the property (`.attr('disabled',disableBtn)`)

Comment: @Pete what I meant is class is not applied after selecting dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addClass` and `removeClass` functions to disable / enable button on the basis of value of `disableBtn` variable.

```
var enableDisableBtn = function(){
    var startVal = $('#datepicker_start').val().trim();
    var endVal = $('#datepicker_end').val().trim();
    var disableBtn =  startVal.length == 0 || endVal.length == 0;
    //$('#btn_download').attr('disabled',disableBtn);
    if(disableBtn) 
      $('#btn_download').addClass('disabled');
    else
      $('#btn_download').removeClass('disabled');
}

$('#datepicker_start, #datepicker_end').on('change blur',function(){
   enableDisableBtn();
});
```

Comment: he has that, this isn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an alternative version. Assuming you need the values later on, you might as well store them while checking. and reuse those set values for both enabling/disabling the button and for getting the values. As suggested onClose is needed, otherwise values typed/pasted directly in the textbox are not caught.

From start to end the code would be something like:

```
var pickers = $('#datepicker_start, #datepicker_end' );
pickers.datepicker({
    onClose: function(){              
        this.Date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");             
        $('#btn_download').toggleClass('disabled', pickers.filter(function(){return this.Date != null;}).length < 2);
            }
        });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/enthx0vh/)

the disabled class is toggled on the hand of all pickers having a Date value (which is filled whenever the picker is closed).